# Promisifying already promise based library with bluebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird, io.js

If a library exposes a promise-based API that is not based on bluebird but does not expose a traditional callback API, is there a way to "promisify" that library to return bluebird promises?

Currently I either just return the promise to a bluebird context, or if I want to use any bluebird specific functions directly then I wrap the call with bluebird's Promise.resolve.

I believe this would be possible with ES2015 proxies, but neither Node.js™, io.js nor Babel support them.

Is there a *sane* way to do this without proxies?

Comment: What promise library are they using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the promisifier option

```
Promise.promisifyAll(lib, {
     promisifier: function(fn) {
         return function () {
              return Promise.resolve(fn.apply(this, arguments));
         }
     }
});
```